# Приложение не подключается к MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

[image: структура бд]    Connection dbConnection;

```
public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    String connectionString="jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbName;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    dbConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);
    return  dbConnection;
}
public void signUpUser(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, String location, String gender){
    String insert="INSERT INTO"+Const.USER_TABLE+"("+Const.USER_FIRSTNAME+","+Const.USER_LASTNAME+","+Const.USER_USERNAME+","+Const.USER_PASSWORD+","+Const.USER_LOCATION+","+Const.USER_GENDER+")";
    try{
    PreparedStatement prSt=getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
    prSt.setString(1, firstName);
    prSt.setString(2, lastName);
    prSt.setString(3, userName);
    prSt.setString(4, password);
    prSt.setString(5, location);
    prSt.setString(6, gender);

        prSt.executeUpdate();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Проблема такая. Я создал приложение где нужно вводить данные для регестрациии. Все эти данные должны заносится в табличку в базе данных. Но они не заносятся. Я все делал по этой интрукции https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ2SCZEkKoQ&t=620s.

Comment: У Вас запрос не правильный, в запросе поля перечислены, а параметры нет. `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Comment: @Z.John у меня просто есть еще класс  public class Const {
    public static final String USER_TABLE="users";
    public static final String USER_ID="idusers";
    public static final String USER_FIRSTNAME="firstname";
    public static final String USER_LASTNAME="lastname";
    public static final String USER_USERNAME="username";
    public static final String USER_PASSWORD="password";
    public static final String USER_GENDER="gender";
    public static final String USER_LOCATION="location";

}

Comment: Ваши константы это перечисление имен полей, а параметры где? Допишите в конец запроса VALUES (:p1, :p2, :p3, ...)

Comment: @Z.John я зделал так String insert="INSERT INTO"+Const.USER_TABLE+"("+Const.USER_FIRSTNAME+","+Const.USER_LASTNAME+","+Const.USER_USERNAME+","+Const.USER_PASSWORD+","+Const.USER_LOCATION+","+Const.USER_GENDER+")"+"VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      и оно чет не добавляет все равно

Comment: а какие-то ошибки в StackTrace пишет?

Comment: @Z.John ну в консоли ошибок нет

Comment: Приложите к вопросу структуру таблицы и лог, чтоб в нем было видно какие данные вы пытаетесь записать и результат подключения к БД.

Comment: @Z.John ну прикрепил

Comment: У вас поле iduser auto increment?

Comment: @Z.John там первые две галочки в Workbanche стоят

Comment: галочка AI стоит? (у меня сейчас нет Workbanche под рукой, на память я не помню порядок галочек :) )

Comment: @Z.John не стоит

Comment: Поставьте, эта галочка чтоб таблица сама создавала идентификаторы (счетчик) Т.к. это поле первичный ключ, оно обязательное, а в запросе вы явно туда значение не передаете

Comment: @Z.John поставил все равно оно не роботает